# Does Soft Proofing to a different profile modify the actual photo

Tags: color-spaces, soft-proofing

Am I right in thinking the difference between using Soft Proofing  to a different colour profile (in Photoshop for example) and just changing the colour profile is that with Soft Proofing use of the Relative/Perceptual options (in Photoshop) actually modifies the values of the pixels before changing profile so when the profile is changed more of the pixels are properly mapped to the new colour model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually not, although I guess it could be done that way. Normally though, pixels are passed though a color transformation on the display path. Some software use a full color matrix but most and certainly hardware based solutions use a 3D LUT (Look-Up-Table) for efficiency.

This means that the same pixel values remain in the image but go through the LUT which sends different values to the display. The 3D LUT does not cover every possible point in the input space so we usually interpolate in-between.

Comment: My plan was to use soft proofing to firstly display version of the image with the same cmyk profile (fogra27) as used by the printer so I can confidently see whether there were any issues, then make adjustments if there were and then export with fogra27 profile.  You seem to be implying its just a display only thing but if I just export as rgb and there are values in there that when converted to CMYK colour space cannot be converted to the fogra7 profile Im the at the mercy of what the printshop does (and there seems to be an issue with blue/greens)

Comment: I think my question was bit unclear it was about the difference between the image displayed when you softproof and the image created when export image using a particular colour profile, I think I should ask a new/different question.